# There is a proper way to run Intel-specific docker containers on Mac M1?

Tags: docker, ibm-mq, apple-m1, podman, colima

Im working on web-application that uses IBM MQ as a message broker. I want to setup environment for integration tests via testcontainers, but there is no IBM MQ container for ARM arhitecture, so using Docker as a container manager is not a proper solution.

I replaced Docker with Podman on Intel machine using [this article](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/piers-walter/2022/07/28/running-x86-64-containers-such-as-mq-on-podman-on) but Podman`s performance dropped significantly (25 seconds to run a container and infinite execution of podman ps) so i dont want to use this mechanism.

Also I've heard of Lima and Colima so now im totally confused and I can't decide what setup for my case is the best.

Comment: see links in this related SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096568/ibm-mq-for-apple-silicon/76590565#76590565

Answer (score 0):

Being architecture independent is one of the benefits of [testcontainers.cloud](https://testcontainers.cloud), a product by the maintainers of the Testcontainers libraries.

When you use Testcontainers Cloud your tests run locally as usual, and the containers are started in an isolated on-demand cloud environment which your tests provision and connect to via a small, user-space agent application.

Testcontainers Cloud is currently in a public beta, and you can evaluate it for your use-cases and setup by joining on the website.